# selectize.js select dropdown show by default opened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js for my search form and want to show select list opened by default.

```
<select id="select-state" name="state[]" multiple class="demo-default" placeholder="Select Models">
 <option value="">Select Models</option>
 <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
 <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
 <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
 <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
 <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
 <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
<script>
$('#select-state').selectize({
    maxItems: 5
});
</script>
```

I have tried different methods but none of them are working.
By jQuery

```
$('#select-state').show().focus().click();
```

By CSS

```
<style>.selectize-dropdown{ display:block!important; visibility:visible!important;}</style>
```

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```js
var select = $('#select-state').selectize({
  maxItems: 5
});
var selectize = select[0].selectize;
selectize.open();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<select id="select-state" name="state[]" multiple class="demo-default" placeholder="Select Models">
  <option value="">Select Models</option>
  <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
  <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
  <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it shows the dropdown immediately when the control receives the focus.

https://selectize.dev/docs/usage#configuration

```
var select = $('#select-state').selectize({
  maxItems: 5,
  openOnFocus: true
});
```